# how get all value Front and back of split function

Tags: jquery, split

I have one split function like -

```js
function solve() {
   str1 = $('#equ').val();
   var eql = str1.split(/=/g);
   var lft = parseInt(eql[0]);
   var rit = parseInt(eql[1]);
   $('#test').text(lft+':'+rit);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter equation" value="-5x-7=108+55" class="equ" id="equ">
<input type="submit" value="solve" class="solve" id="solve" onclick="solve()">

<p id="test"></p>
```

only get two value.remaining "**(x-7) & +55**" are missing.please help me to get all value front and back.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `parseInt()`, remove it.

```
var lft = eql[0];
var rit = eql[1];
```

```js
function solve() {
  str1 = $('#equ').val();
  var eql = str1.split(/=/g);
  var lft = eql[0];
  var rit = eql[1];
  $('#test').text(lft + ':' + rit);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter equation" value="-5x-7=108+55" class="equ" id="equ">
<input type="submit" value="solve" class="solve" id="solve" onclick="solve()">

<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove parseInt() to get entire string:

```
function solve() {
str1 = $('#equ').val();
var eql = str1.split("=");
     var lft = eql[0];
     var rit = eql[1];
     $('#test').text(lft+':'+rit);
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of answer after mins and with no value addition?

Answer (score 0):

use eval() function of jquery

also `x`  is not operator in jquery, please use `*` for multiplication.

[**Please see this link for eval()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

here is **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydtw99sp/)**

```js
function solve() {
str1 = $('#equ').val();
var eql = str1.split(/=/g);
     var lft = eval(eql[0]);
     var rit = eval(eql[1]);
      $('#test').text(lft+':'+rit);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter equation" value="-5*-7=108+55" class="equ" id="equ">
<input type="submit" value="solve" class="solve" id="solve" onclick="solve()">

<p id="test"></p>
```